# Why font-size in em's with important doesn't override font-size in px?

Tags: css

First things first - here is a fiddle, so you may scroll the code down: http://jsfiddle.net/Usurer/f5E7R/4/

I have a simple construction:

```
<div class='parent flex'>
    <div class='child-px'>
        abc
    </div>
    <div class='child-em'>
        abc
    </div>
</div>
```

supplied with stylesheet:

```
.flex { 
    font-size: .5em !important;
}

.parent {
    font-size: 1.5em;
}

.child-px {
    font-size: 20px;
}
.child-em {
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

My trouble is that .flex doesn't override .child-px. But why? Why?
(I use Chrome v.33 if it matters)

### ---------------------------------

Now I've got it - child-em has changed font-size because, being em-based, it takes it from parent, not because it's font-size gets modified by .flex rule. And child-px doesn't care because its font-size is set in pixels.

Comment: Your css doesn't match the fiddle.  The fiddle uses a percentage for the flex class instead of an em. Change it to a specified em and it works.

Comment: My bad. I've fixed the link, though it seems to be similar be it percent or em.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This answer is based on your [posted fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f5E7R/1/) in which:*

```css
.flex { 
    font-size: 50% !important;
}
```

---

First of all, I should note that `px` is an [**absolute unit**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#Absolute_length_units) which unlike `em`, is not relative to the parent's font size. So it would be constant.

And in the demo you've provided, you'll get the value of `font-size` of the `.child-em` is pixels Because jQuery `.css()` method returns the computed style of elements.

From the **[jQuery doc](http://api.jquery.com/css/)**:

> `.css( propertyName )`
>   Get the computed style properties for the first element in the set of
>   matched elements.

In this particular case, you have change the font size of the parent to `50%` of the default (which is `16px` in most web browsers) by `.flex` class name, and then double that value again for the `.child-em` element by `2em`.

Therefor the returned value would be `16px`.

Comment: Yes, it does change child-em's font-size, but child-px is still 20px, ain't it?

Comment: @Usurer Yes it is, because unlike `em`, `px` is an absolute unit. It is not relative to the parent's font size.

Comment: Oh. That's it. Thanks a lot. I'm really ashamed now 'cause surely I've read it many times before and had successfully forgotten.

Answer (score 4):

That's because you've given `.child-px` its own font size. That alone is enough to prevent the font size of `.flex` from being inherited.

Even though you have the `!important` on `.flex`, the importance is only applied to that element. It doesn't affect any other elements, in particular it does not force descendants to inherit the value from it instead of using their own specified value.

Comment: Oh, that's tricky. I can't upvote your reply (because of reputation) or mark it as answer ('cause I've already marked one by Hashem Qolami), but I'm very grateful since you've helped me to understand the whole thing.